# WP7 Developpement : How to make the program wait until the end of an EventHandler?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

When my view wants the value of LogoStation, it returns null because my program has not yet executed LoadStation_Completed.

I want my program waits that LoadStation_Completed is executed before continuing.

Thx

```
public class Infos
{
    #region propriétés

    private DataServiceCollection<SyndicObject> _infosStation;
    public DataServiceCollection<SyndicObject> InfosStation
    {
        get
        {
            return _infosStation;
        }
        set
        {
            _infosStation = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    string nameStation;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private ImageSource _logoStation;
    public ImageSource LogoStation
    {
        get
        {
            return _logoStation;
        }
        set
        {
            _logoStation = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("LogoStation");
        }
    }

    public Infos(string station)
    {
        nameStation = station;
        getInfos();
    }

    public void getInfos()
    {
        SyndicationContext service = new SyndicationContext(new Uri("http://test/817bee9d-faf4-4680-9d05-e41c2c90ae5a/"));

        IQueryable<SyndicObject> requete = (from objectSki in service.Objects
                                           where objectSki.NOMSTATION == nameStation
                                           select objectSki);

        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            InfosStation = new DataServiceCollection<SyndicObject>();
            InfosStation.LoadCompleted += new EventHandler<LoadCompletedEventArgs>(InfoStation_LoadCompleted);   
            InfosStation.LoadAsync(requete);
        }
        );
    }

    void InfoStation_LoadCompleted(object sender, LoadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        LogoStation = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"http://test/upload/" + InfosStation[0].LOGO, UriKind.Absolute));
    }
}
```

Comment: By using the property setter you are using `NotifyPropertyChanged` (correctly) to tell the UI bound to `LogoStation` that it has been updated. This should mean that the UI will display nothing initially and then the image when the load has completed. Without seeing your view code what you have here looks correct.

Comment: Put the section of your program that wants to wait that  LoadStation_Completed is executed into the InfoStation_LoadCompleted callback.

Comment: @ChrisF : thx, but i think that my NotifyPropertyChanged doesn't work

Comment: @MartinJames To put my properties Logostation into InfoStation_LoadCompleted ??

Comment: You don't want to block your UI for a service call like this. Have a placeholder image, load the image before you get to the page, or have a non-blocking loading indicator

Comment: Eureka ! Thanks @ChrisF ! my class did not inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged so my NotifyPropertyChanged didn't work !

Comment: @Viiink - I'll put that in an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the property setter you are using `NotifyPropertyChanged` (correctly) to tell the UI bound to `LogoStation` that it has been updated. This should mean that the UI will display nothing initially and then the image when the load has completed.

Without seeing your view code what you have here looks correct - apart from the fact that your `Infos` class **doesn't** inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged`. This means that the event never gets sent.

Update your class definition and you should be good to go.